# Node js proper module imports

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

Recently I was learning about the Sequelize module and used the following in my code to import the module:

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize')

const sequelize = new Sequelize( ... {
    ...
})
```

Every thing worked as expected, db connection, queries, updates, deletes, etc, the only issue was that my auto complete was totally broken.

After looking at the docs I found the proper way to import was to use destructuring and now my auto complete started to work

```
const { Sequelize } = require('sequelize')
```

My question is, if the first import was incorrect why was the module still able to function correctly? Is there some functionality that is able to find the correct object that I was trying to use, but the language server was unable to find it?

Comment: “*the language server*” Do you mind linking a document that explains what this is? I’ve never heard the term before and would love to know to what you are referring.

Comment: Guessing here but perhaps the Sequelize `.d.ts` file doesn't have a type definition for the default / root export where it does for the named `Sequelize` export. Do you get autocomplete if you use the first option with `new Sequelize.Sequelize()`?

Comment: @esqew https://microsoft.github.io/language-server-protocol/ the language server is what handles all the parsing of the code syntax, grammer, etc

Comment: @Phil No, it recognizes it as a constant but no suggestions when I press "."